# Any way to get all fillable fields by simple SQL query for Laravel Model?

Tags: mysql

Laravel model contain two value,

```
protected $table = 'table_name';
protected $fillable = [
 'field_name1',
 'field_name2'
];
```

When there are many fields in a table. It's need more time to copy one by one from table and paste. Is there any shortcut way to get all fields name including " (quotation) by SQL query.

Comment: Have you tried backing up and restoring?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-methods.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MySQL Query :**

```
SELECT CONCAT('"',COLUMN_NAME,'",') as fillable
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'my_table';
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such command. You should use `mysqldump` tool to do so.

Please also note that

```
CREATE TABLE table1 as SELECT * FROM table2;
```

It will create table with the same architecture, but without indexes, better to use:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 like table2;
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2;
```

For getting all tables you can use:

```
show tables
```

You may also need to copy views, trigers, events, functions

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure of your use case, but I would recommend [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)

With this you can dump your database into one SQL file and then reload it into the new database with:

```
mysqldump -u root -p password databaseName > /path/databaseName.sql
mysql -u root -p password newDatabaseName < /path/databaseName.sql
```

However, this requires that you use the command line, and have the new database created already.

Note: Using login credentials in the command line is not recommended.

Comment: Note: that this answer was for the original question that was subsequently rewritten completely.